# Flutter - how to map a network drive using smb in a MacOS app?

Tags: macos, flutter, smb

My macOS app needs to tell the Finder to open a shared drive on smb:// protocol

I've tried using the html package, but that did not work:

```
var url = "smb://myserver.com"
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
}
```

I've also tried url_launcher, but the documentation already says it does not support mapping a network drive, only http, https, mailto, tel, and sms

My guess is that the MacOS api is still not mature enough so this does not exist?

Searched everywhere... thank you in advance!

Comment: The macOS API is stable, so there's no reason a plugin couldn't be written. When you say you tried url_launcher, did you add the url_launcher_fde plugin from the FDE repo? If not you didn't have macOS support at all in the plugin, in which case you weren't really testing anything.

Comment: Thank you smorgan- going to look into the FDE repo - total noob here.